# Getting the recommended resolution for computer in Code

Tags: c#, screen-resolution

Ok, I know there are similar threads about this issue, but none of them really fit my case:

If I go to my desktop, click on screen resolution, I have a menu with a recommended resolution. I want to get this from code (C#).

My Code looks like this:

```
public static Size GetOptimalScreenResolution()
    {
        var scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope();
        var query = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_VideoControllerResolution");
        UInt32 maxHResolution = 0;
        UInt32 maxVResolution = 0;
        using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            var results = searcher.Get();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                if ((UInt32)item["HorizontalResolution"] > maxHResolution)
                    maxHResolution = (UInt32)item["HorizontalResolution"];

                if ((UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"] > maxVResolution)
                    maxVResolution = (UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"];
            } 
        }
        return new Size(maxHResolution, maxVResolution);
    }
```

In my desktop, the recommended resolution is 1680 X 1050.
What this method returns is 1680 X 1280.
**This means that the recommended resolution is not necessary the maximum one horizontally and vertically. How to I get the value of 1680 X 1050?** Thank you!!!

Comment: Firstly there is a (at least on a logical level) issue in you logic above, you are basically assuming, by looking for max horizontal and vertical resolution _seperately_ that if a display can support X*Y and A*B it can also support X*B and A*Y, which may not be the case...

Comment: A very good point. There is no such resolution as 1680 X 1280. Will fix it and update you. Thanks!

Comment: Id just go for maxRes = hRes * vRes in your loop and store the h and v for that.  I cant see anyway to get the recommended res though (which is not to say i'm not failing to look in the right place).

Comment: Is there the possibility that the max resolution is not the recommended one? The recommended one is the one natively supported by the hardware.

Comment: @SoMos People with vision impairments sometimes buy the monitor with the largest dimensions they can find, then crank down the resolution. In any case, it's possible, so better account for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution - thanks to tolanj

```
 public static Size GetOptimalScreenResolution()
    {
        var scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope();
        var query = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_VideoControllerResolution");
        UInt32 maxHResolution = 0;
        UInt32 maxVResolution = 0;
        UInt32 maxHForMaxVResolution = 0;
        using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            var results = searcher.Get();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                if ((UInt32) item["HorizontalResolution"] >= maxHResolution)
                {
                    maxHResolution = (UInt32) item["HorizontalResolution"];
                    if ((UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"] > maxVResolution || maxHForMaxVResolution != maxHResolution)
                    {
                        maxVResolution = (UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"];
                        maxHForMaxVResolution = (UInt32)item["HorizontalResolution"]; 
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        return new Size(maxHResolution, maxVResolution);
    }
```